# Can a new-user comment and answer? Is a feedback to an answer allowed to be posted as an answer?

Tags: support, comments, moderation, new-users, deleted-answers

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [How do I get the grub menu to show on a MacBook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220175/how-do-i-get-the-grub-menu-to-show-on-a-macbook/1314400#1314400)

My post was not an answer but a comment, not sure if that's the reason because has been deleted.
I can't post comment because I just registered. I'm not new to *nix and I'm in love with Ubuntu since maany years.
I decided to register to give my appreciation to a user posting a reaaly long and detailed description, and give my result to others.. just trying to contribute for the little I felt/could.
So, just that, feeling strange in having the post deleted.
All the best, and thanks for everything, you rocks.

Comment: You can post questions and answers, but you can't comment others posts yet. As soon as you get some rep points, you'll be able to comment all questions and answers. You can ask a question and add a link to another question there as well. See https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

The Help Center [explains](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers) that answers that do not provide an answer to the original question will be deleted. The structure of this site doesn't support posting a comment on another post as an answer, because the general idea is to make it as easy as possible to find the best answer to the question. So:

- Posts that don't answer the question would be "noise", causing answer seekers to spend more time looking for the solution they need.
- Answers to a question are independent. By default they are displayed according to score, highest at the top, so a post that is intended as a comment on another post may not appear anywhere near that post, the author won't be notified (as they are when a comment is posted on their post), so a comment posted as an answer is likely to cause only confusion to readers.

Instead of writing a post (or even a comment) to say "thanks", we upvote the post that helped. You need 15 [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) for your votes to affect the post score, but clicks on the vote buttons by low-reputation and unregistered users are counted and recorded in the public database which can be queried [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

You need to gain 50 reputation to post comments - the idea of this is to prevent spam.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
All this is very clear to me, I appreciate.
So .. I'll try to have few points to be able to insert this comment!
^_^

Comment: @atlasan all the best!